# Handling method returning void uniformly with method returning a value

Tags: c++

I have a helper function like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename Arg0>
void callMethod(Data *data, T &object, R (T::*method)(Arg0)) {
    push(data, (object.*method)(get<Arg0>(data, 1)));
}
```

where `push` pushes result into data, and `get` gets arguments from data. Using boost preprocessor I have defined this function for various number of arguments.

The problem is when a method returns `void` (`R` is `void`) the code does not compile because `void` is not a valid argument/parameter to the `push` function. In case of a `void` return value I would like to just call the method and not call `push`. What is the best way to do so?

Overloading does not help as then the call to the `callMethod` is ambiguous:

```
template<typename T, typename Arg0>
void callMethod(Data *data, T &object, void (T::*method)(Arg0)) {
    (object.*method)(get<Arg0>(data, 1));
}
```

Comment: Overloading should work fine; the ambiguity is resolved in favour of the second overload.  What error do you get?

Comment: @ecatmur: VS 2012 issues C2668 - ambiguous call to overloaded function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename Arg0>
typename enable_if<is_void<R>::value == false>::type
callMethod(Data *data, T &object, R (T::*method)(Arg0)) {
    push(data, (object.*method)(get<Arg0>(data, 1)));
}

template<typename T, typename R, typename Arg0>
typename enable_if<is_void<R>::value == true>::type
callMethod(Data *data, T &object, R (T::*method)(Arg0)) {
    (object.*method)(get<Arg0>(data, 1));
}
```